# Tabular - shift column to center without removing right align

Tags: tables

I create the following table:

[image]

with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{multicol, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}

\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{L{5.75cm}|R{1.25cm}|R{1.25cm}|R{1.25cm}|R{1.25cm}|R{1.25cm}|R{1.25cm}|R{1.25cm}}
    \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Table 2: GDP by Economic Activity (at constant 2015 prices)}} \\ 
    \hline\hline
    & \multirowcell{3}{2019 \\ share \\ \%} &    \multicolumn{6}{c}{Annual growth, \%} \\
    \hhline{~~------} 
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2018} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!10!white} 2019} \\
    \hhline{~~------} 
    & &  3Q & 4Q & 1Q & 2Q & 3Q & {\cellcolor{blue!10!white} 4Q} \\ 
    \hline
    Services  & 57.7 & 7.3 &6.9 &    &    &    &   \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
    Manufacturing     & 22.3 &  5.0   &   4.7 &    &    &    &  \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
    Mining            &  7.1 &  $-$5.7   &   $-$0.7 &    &    &    &  \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
    Agriculture       &  7.1 &  $-$0.8   &  $-$0.1  &    &    &    &  \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
    Construction      &  4.7 &  4.7   &    2.6&    &    &    &  \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\ \hline
    Real GDP$^1$      &  100.0 & 4.4    &   4.7 &    &    &    & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{l}{\small $^1$Shares do not add up due to rounding and exclusion of import duties.}         \\
    \multicolumn{8}{l}{\small Source: Department of Statistics Malaysia}   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

What I want to change is to 'shift' the last 6 columns to the left (the columns with sub-headers 3Q, 4Q, etc), but without removing the right-align.

The reason for this is that typographically, numbers should be right-aligned for ease of reading. However, I'd like the entire block of right-aligned numbers to be centered for aesthetics.

An analog of this would be:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}
\flushright
Text
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Such that the minipage itself is centred, but the text within is not.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If I understand well, you would like to have the numbers centred, but aligned on the decimal dot?

Comment: That's exactly right!

Comment: Have you tried the `dcolumn` package? This package comes with the LaTeX tools (no extra installation required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `S` column type (from `siunitx`) is done for you!. I added some simplifications: when you load `xcolor`, you don't have to load `color`. Similarly, loading it with option `[table]` loads `colortbl`. I took the liberty to group the notes at the bottom of the table on the same line, but you can easily revert to your original layout if you prefer.

Note that in `S` columns, non-numeric cells have their contents centred if you add a pair of braces around the contents.

```
\documentclass[border = 6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multicol, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{table-format=-1.1, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.25cm}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{L{5.75cm}|S[table-format=3.1]|*{5}{S|}S}
    \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Table 2: GDP by Economic Activity (at constant 2015 prices)}} \\
    \hline\hline
    & {\multirowcell{3}{2019 \\ share \\ \%}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Annual growth, \%} \\
    \hhline{~~------}
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2018} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!10!white} 2019} \\
    \hhline{~~------}
    & & {3Q} & {4Q} & {1Q} & {2Q} & {3Q} & {\cellcolor{blue!10!white} 4Q} \\
    \hline
    Services & 57.7 & 7.3 &6.9 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
    Manufacturing & 22.3 & 5.0 & 4.7 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
    Mining & 7.1 & -5.7 & -0.7 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
    Agriculture & 7.1 & -0.8 & -0.1 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
    Construction & 4.7 & 4.7 & 2.6& & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\ \hline
    Real GDP$^1$ & 100.0 & 4.4 & 4.7 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\small $^1$Shares do not add up due to rounding and exclusion of import duties.}
   & \multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\small Source: Department of Statistics Malaysia} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a vertical is missing

Comment: Thank you so much! Could I ask why the table format in the second column is 3.1, but 1.1 for the overall table?

Comment: the 3.1 accounts for the 100.1

Comment: @jsbibra: where?

Comment: @Bernard between all the Q columns

Comment: @jsbibra: Oh! yes. I had modified the table preamble and placed erroneously the last `S`. Fixed. Thank you for pointing it!