# siunitx - numbers are not centred

Tags: tables

This is a follow up to a [previous question I asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532738/tabular-shift-column-to-center-without-removing-right-align/532745#532745).

I create the following table:

[image]

With this code:

```
\documentclass[border = 6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multicol, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.1, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=1.25cm}
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{L{5.75cm}|S[table-format=3.2]|*{5}{S|}S}
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Table 2: GDP by Economic Activity (at constant 2015 prices)}} \\
        \hline\hline
        & {\multirowcell{3}{2019 \\ share \\ \%}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Annual growth, \%} \\
        \hhline{~~------}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2018} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!10!white} 2019} \\
        \hhline{~~------}
        & & {3Q} & {4Q} & {1Q} & {2Q} & {3Q} & {\cellcolor{blue!10!white} 4Q} \\
        \hline
        Services & 57.7 & 7.3 & 6.9 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
        Manufacturing & 22.3 & 5.0 & 4.7 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
        Mining & 7.1 & 5.7 & 0.7 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
        Agriculture & 7.1 & 0.8 & 0.1 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\
        Construction & 4.7 & 4.7 & 2.6& & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\ \hline
        Real GDP$^1$ & 100.0 & 4.4 & 4.7 & & & & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\small $^1$Shares do not add up due to rounding and exclusion of import duties.}
        & \multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\small Source: Department of Statistics Malaysia} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you notice, the numbers in columns 3 and 4 (headed 3Q and 4Q for 2018) are not centred even though none of the numbers are negative (that was the reason for the off-center in the previous question).

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Your standard table format is `table-format=-1.1` and so siunitx reserves the place for the minus.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't notice that little devil ;)